# Exception while running SUP101 on ios device

Tags: ios, xcode, sup

I am testing the SUP101 application for ios and facing this exception of Sync failed. I have tried redeploying the package(.pkg). Created the MBOs again. Generated the APIs again but still the same error. Following is the error that i am getting:

```
[ERROR] [MBODataManager.m:134] SUPPersistenceException: SUPPersistenceException from synchronize: -- SUPSynchronizeException: Sync failed: -1305 (MOBILINK_COMMUNICATIONS_ERROR) %1:63 %2: %3:51Details:
```

Answer (score 1):

A Mobilink error has 3 parameters %1 %2 and %3. The meaning of the parameters can be found here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00462.1540/reference/messages/msgnum2993.html

The first parameter is the error code in mobilink. In your case this is 63 and this is a socket error.
Error codes and their explaination can be found here: http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/saerrors/mlcomm-errors-by-code.html

Without more information about your server configuration and code snippets especially concerning the connection profile and sync profile there isn't really anything more to say about this error.